# How to replace one character from regex search in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to search and replace an error from a formula in a sheet, Please see the sample data below :

```
SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!E:E)-SUM(E102:E104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="F105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!F:F)-SUM(F102:F104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="G105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!G:G)-SUM(G102:G104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="H105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!H:H)-SUM(H102:H104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="I105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!I:I)-SUM(I102:I104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="J105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!J:J)-SUM(J102:J104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="K105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!K:K)-SUM(K102:K104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="L105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!L:L)-SUM(L102:L104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="M105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!M:M)-SUM(M102:M104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="N105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!N:N)-SUM(N102:N104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="O105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!O:O)-SUM(O102:O104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="P105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!P:P)-SUM(P102:P104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="Q105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!Q:Q)-SUM(Q102:Q104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="R105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!R:R)-SUM(R102:R104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="S105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!S:S)-SUM(S102:S104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="T105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt; "",SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!T:T)-SUM(T102:T104),"")</f><v/></c><c r="U105" s="36" t="str"><f>IF(B105 &lt;&gt;
```

I need to replace the number in second SUM's first range to always be 5. For example SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!T:T)-SUM(T102:T104) should be corrected to SUM(ZeplinUpdateTracker!T:T)-SUM(T5:T104)

I have written regex as -SUM([A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9] which effectively search all target data, but I am not able to write the replace regex as -SUM([A-Z]5 replaces literally with [A-Z]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you could look for:

```
(SUM\([A-Z]+)\d+
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PpWXdZ/1)

- `(` - Open 1st capture group.

  - `SUM\(` - Literal match for `SUM(`.
  - `[A-Z]+` - One or more uppercase letters.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
- `\d+` - One or more digits

Replace with:

```
\15
```

- `\1` - Whatever is inside 1st capture group.
- `5` - A literal 5.

**Note:** Make sure you tick 'Regular Expressions'

[image]

Comment: Curious why it's downvoted. It replaces every second `SUM`. Please elaborate.

Comment: Not sure who down voted this and why but this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. I accept this as the answet

Comment: Oh great , Thanks for the tip. I will do the same. Also I have a follow up question if you don't mind. So \1 in the replace means whatever was found in between first ( and +) will be stores as $1 , right ? So like wise is it possible to do another ( +) and store in $2 ?

Comment: Not my downvote, but your regex doesn't actually target the _second_ occurrence, which was a requirement given in the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I read it as every second occurence of the word sum in each formula. Technically that's not the second occurence overall, which you have taken as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern seems to be working:

```
^(.*?\bSUM.*?SUM\([A-Z]+)\d+(:[A-Z]+\d+\).*)$
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation on the regex pattern:

```
^                     from the start of the string
    (.*?\bSUM         match and capture in $1 everything up to including the first SUM
    .*?SUM\(          as well as the second SUM
    [A-Z]+)           making sure to capture the letter from the first cell reference
    \d+               but do NOT capture the digit (we want to replace with 5)
    (:[A-Z]+\d+\).*)  then match and capture the rest of the formula in $2
$
```

We then replace with `$15$2` to get the output you want.

Comment: This doesn't seems to work, entire sheet gets selected when I search with this regex. JvdV's response works perfectly with minimal regex

Comment: It is working in the demo.  You must have some other problem on your end.

Comment: I can see that , I will check what is the problem at my end. Thanks a lot for the help.